# JavaScript Consultation needed with (in HTML5 context)

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas

It is a hobby project with a friend, 
but since I will invest in it (for UI/UX design) I need to be sure about feasability.
I am a programmer myself but I do not consider being experienced with JS and HTML5.

[Description]

I will be doing this kind of project BUT in JS and Html5 not Flash or Silverlight.
Here is the list of questions about feasabilities with JavaScript and HTML5: https://www.greetingbee.com/card-studio.aspx

- we drag drop and manipulate images and in the end we want to save the greeting card (the composed surface) as image file...

  1. how to do it without canvas? to printscreen or generate an image of specific area of html composition (DOM)
  2. how to do it with canvas? keeping in mind performance ?
- using SVG and/or PNG for keeping quality of shapes of greeting cards againts resizing etc.. any suggestions and tools recommendations
- is there a JS script that could be used to make browser support some HTML5 features if it is not supporting some things, like make browser emulate and support :)), I do not like this question myself but who knows ))

I know its abit unusual case but we all might benefit if those answers find solutions and tips.

I share these links which have some sort of solutions: 
www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12652769/rendering-html-elements-to-canvas/12660867#12660867

I know about html2Canvas which is said to be not so perfect, and Modernizer script that help to determine html5 features with browser

Comment: from canvas you can get the image as a byte stream and send to server to store some where. You may get the whole canvas OR you can get a portion if it too.

Comment: You can also get away with doing all of the image blending serverside and just implementing a functional drag/drop UI with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do it without canvases but with them there is `toDataURL` method. You can read about it here: http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

If You want to save image on server-side you could send data returned by `toDataURL()` to your server through AJAX or smthing like that.

As for second question about emulation of HTML5 there is a piece of code which enables you to use canvas tag on old IEs http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/